# how to view function in brackets

Tags: javascript, shell, meteor

I tried searching for possible ways of finding the function definition which is shown as `[Function]` on server.

**Example**:

```
 Meteor.publish gives [Function]
 on Meteor shell , but how to get the detailed description of function`
```

`

Comment: Are you asking how does one print said function out?  If so, I think you can simply call `functionName.toString()` like `console.log('func: ', myFunction.toString());` and it will literally print it out.

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like  as @codechimp said , we can use `Function.toString()`